# Need help solving three nonlinear equations with two unknowns

Tags: abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Could you please help me to solve the system for c and d:

$c^2 + (2d - 5/2)c + (3d)/2 - 1/2 = 0$

$d^2 + (2c - 5/2)d + (3c)/2 - 3/2 = 0$

$-c^2d - (9c^2)/4 - cd^2 + (cd)/2 + 6c + (3d^2)/4 - 7d + 9/4 = 0$

when I used MATLAB with "solve", this is what I got:

Empty sym: 0-by-1

Empty sym: 0-by-1

So MATLAB could not find any answer. So I tried to solve it by myself and I got some answers but when I substituted in the LHS of the equations, I did not get zero. So there are some mistakes in my answers but I don't know where.

Any help in how to find solutions for this system? or can you tell me what is wrong with my answer below.

Adding the idea of my answer:

I multiply Eq.1 by $d$ and Eq.2 by $c$ and adding the new two equations together and got

$3c^2d + (3c^2)/2 + 3cd^2 - 5cd - (3c)/2 + (3d^2)/2 - d/2 = 0$

then I found $cd^2+dc^2$ from this equation and substitute it in Eq.3 in the question and I got

$(11c)/2 - (43d)/6 - (7cd)/6 - (7c^2)/4 + (5d^2)/4 + 9/4 = 0$

and if we substitute $c^2$ from Eq.1  and $d^2$ from Eq.2 from the question in this equation  we got

$cd = 39/2 - (17d)/2 - (9c)/2$

hence,  from this equation we  find $d$ ($d = -(9c - 39)/(2c + 17)$) and also if we substitute $cd$ from this equation in  Eq.1 and Eq.2 in the question we got these two equations:

$c^2 = (23c)/2 + (31d)/2 - 77/2$

$d^2 = (15c)/2 + (39d)/2 - 75/2$

then if we substitute the value of $d = -(9c - 39)/(2c + 17)$ in these two equations we got

$c^2 = (23c^2 - 21c - 50)/(2c + 17)$

$(9c - 39)^2/(2c + 17)^2 = (15c)/2 - (39(9c - 39))/(2(2c + 17)) - 75/2$

which are equivalent to these two equations:(by multiplying the first one by $(2c + 17)$ and second one by $(2c + 17)^2$)

$2c^3 - 6c^2 + 21c + 50 = 0$

$81c^2 - 702c + 1521 = 30c^3 + 9c^2 - 1845c + 2091$

then in these two equations if we find $c^3$ from the first one($c^3 = 3c^2 - (21c)/2 - 25$) and substitute it in the second one we got

$81c^2 - 702c + 1521 = 99c^2 - 2160c + 1341$

and if we solve this equation, we have

$c = 81/2 - \sqrt(6601)/2$

$c= 81/2+\sqrt(6601)/2 $

therefore we found some solutions of this system!

If we assume the calculation in these steps are correct(which I did it by Matlab), what are the mathematical mistakes in these steps?(please let me know all the mistakes if you find more then one)

Comment: are you sure that a solution exists? Maybe Matlab told you that there is no solution.

Comment: @Surb: Mathematica agrees with your conclusion - no solutions exist.

Comment: If you subtract the second equation from the first, you get a quadratic that you can solve for $c$ in terms of $d$.  Then you you can try plugging the solutions (there are two of them, naturally) into the third equation.  You'll get an equation in the single variable $d$, and you can try to analyze it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I just add the idea of my answer can you look at it and tell me what  mistakes I made?

Comment: Three equations, two unknowns. I'd guess there is no solution (except by chance. Try solving pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $3$ equations in $2$ unknowns, so unless you know for a fact that there is a solution, you should expect that the system might be inconsistent.

And in fact, that's the case here.

Considering only the first two equations, we get the equivalent system
$$
\begin{cases}
6c^4-26c^3-18c^2+27c+10=0\\[4pt]
31d = -24c^3+122c^2-35c-43\\
\end{cases}
$$
Solving numerically, we get the $4$ solutions
\begin{align*}
(c,d)&\approx 
(-1.065872615, 5.224837188)\\[4pt]
(c,d)&\approx 
(-.3345918428, -.5397478364)\\[4pt]
(c,d)&\approx 
(.9838796319, .5743420457)\\[4pt]
(c,d)&\approx 
(4.749918159, -.9260980641)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
however none of the above pairs $(c,d)$ satisfy the third equation.

Therefore the given system has no solutions.

As regards the error in your analysis . . .

It's not that you made an algebraic error.

As I noted in the comments, all you found are *potential* solutions.

Based on your work, it follows that *if* $(c,d)$ is a solution to the original system, then 
\begin{align*}
(c,d)&={\small{\left(\frac{81+\sqrt{6601}}{2},\frac{-19-\sqrt{6601}}{26}\right)}}\\[4pt]
&\;\text{or}\\[4pt]
(c,d)&={\small{\left(\frac{81-\sqrt{6601}}{2},\frac{-19+\sqrt{6601}}{26}\right)}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
However it's easily verified that neither of the above pairs is an actual solution to the original system, and from that, it follows that the original system has no solutions.

Let me illustrate your misconception with a much simpler example . . .

Consider the following system
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y^2-xy=1&\;\;\;(\text{eq}1)\\[4pt]
x+y^2+xy=3&\;\;\;(\text{eq}2)\\[4pt]
x+y^2+y=5&\;\;\;(\text{eq}3)\\
\end{cases}
$$
of $3$ non-linear equations in the $2$ unknowns $x,y$.

Computing 
$$(\text{eq}1)+(\text{eq}2)-2(\text{eq}3)$$
we get $y=3$.

Replacing $y$ by $3$ in $(\text{eq}3)$, we get $x=-7$.

So we've found the solution $(x,y)=(-7,3)$, right?

Wrong!

As explained, the result $(x,y)=(-7,3)$ is only a *necessary* condition, i.e., a *potential* solution.

To see if it's an *actual* solution, we need to test it to see if it satisfies the original system.

Noting that $(x,y)=(-7,3)$ doesn't satisfy $(\text{eq}1)$, it follows that the original system has no solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just add the idea of my answer can you look at it and tell me what  mistakes I made?

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: Right off the bat, even if you made no algebraic errors, all you found is a potential solution. If a potential solution doesn't satisfy the original system, it should be rejected.

Comment: Why after replacing $cd^2+c^2d$ in Eq.3 do you still end up with a $c^2d$ term?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the same equation before replacing. I  correct my answer (writing the correct equation after replacing $cd^2+c^2d$


.

Comment: @user130281: I'll take another look.

Comment: @user130281: I've updated my answer to critique your attempted solution.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I really appreciate it. It correct some of my mathematical concepts. Is it possible for this behaviour to appear with a system of linear equation?

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage that the first equation is linear in $d$, we have, assuming that $c \neq -\frac 34$,
$$d=\frac{-2 c^2+5 c+1}{4 c+3}$$
Plugging in the second and third equations, we have
$$6 c^4-26 c^3-18 c^2+27 c+10=0\tag1$$
$$4 c^4-31 c^3+50 c^2+74 c-17=0\tag 2$$
Each of these can be solved with nasty radicals. The first one as solutions
$$\{c_1= -1.06587\},\{c_2= -0.334592\},\{c_3= 0.98388\},\{c_4= 4.74992\}$$ and the second one has only two real roots
$$\{c_5= -1.04221\},\{c_6= 0.204876\}$$ If you consider the norm
$$\Phi=(6 c^4-26 c^3-18 c^2+27 c+1)^2+(4 c^4-31 c^3+50 c^2+74 c-17)^2$$ it does not show any real root and its minimum value is $1.26204$ obtained for $c_*=-1.04449$.

We can notice that $c_*$ is "quite close" to $c_1$ and $c_5$. So, maybe, there could be a typo in one of the equations.

**Edit**

Naming $f_1,f_2,f_3$ the three equations, let us consider the norm
$$\Phi=f_1^2+f_2^2+f_3^2$$ and minimize it. Solving in the real domain the eqauions
$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial d}=0$ reveals $7$ soutions.

Minimizing $\Phi$ leads to a minimum value equal to $0.34515$ for $c=0.88087$ and $d=0.75068$.

$3D$ and contour plots of $\Phi$ reveal the same.

All of the above seems to confirm that there is no solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Just to let you know that I did not take this question from a book. I got these equations from my research and I am sure they are correct but I am not sure if they have solutions. In case they have solutions, this will help me in my research.

Comment: @user130281. PLease, have a look at my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any information about this norm and how it is related with the solutions of nonlinear equations system. Could you please give me any recourse about this relation, so I can understand how you concluded that there is no solutions for this system.

Comment: @user130281. Don't worry : you will learn about it. Suppose that you face $m$ equations for $n$ variables $(m > n)$ (this is your case). If you sum the squares of the equations (this is $\Phi$ which we shall try to minimize), it has $n$ derivatives and this makes now a square system of equations to solve. If the system is consistent, at solution $\Phi=0$ and, in order to have $0$, all starting equations are zero. Simple, isn't it ?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Now I understand.